# Index was outside the bounds of the array - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting this issue with Entity Framework, happening in only one application, the same code works fine for others in my team. At the same time I don't have any problem with other applications in my local. Very strange!

My code is something like below, getting the error all over the place(wherever access the tables). Even verified my edmx file, looks fine. The same edmx works fine for others though:

```
tblTest testEntity = _repositoryFactory.Create<tblTest>().Query()
                .SingleOrDefault(t => t.pkTest_ID == 100);
```

Here is the exception detail:

> An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Source:

```
System.Xml
```

StackTrace:

```
at System.Xml.Schema.RangeContentValidator.ValidateElement(XmlQualifiedName name, ValidationState context, Int32& errorCode)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateElementContext(XmlQualifiedName elementName, Boolean& invalidElementInContext)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateElement(String localName, String namespaceUri, XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo, String xsiType, String xsiNil, String xsiSchemaLocation, String xsiNoNamespaceSchemaLocation)
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent()
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.Parse(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.EntityContainer.HandleAssociationSetElement(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.EntityContainer.HandleElement(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.ParseElement(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.Parse(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleEntityContainerTypeElement(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleElement(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.ParseElement(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.Parse(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleTopLevelSchemaElement(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.InternalParse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, IList`1& schemaCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModelOption, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, ItemCollection itemCollection, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean skipInitialization)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadEdmItemCollection(MetadataArtifactLoader loader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.<>c__DisplayClass5.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__0(String k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace(String cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace(DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor, ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, Translator translator, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Crius.Sites.BackOffice.Controllers.ErrorController.Index(String id) in c:\Crius\DotNet\Crius.Sites\Crius.Sites.BackOffice\branches\v15\Crius.Sites.BackOffice\Controllers\ErrorController.cs:line 37
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
As per the response from BlueRaja - Danny(some reason it got deleted) I verified the mappings in edmx, everything looks good. More over the same edmx works in other machines. Even I tried pretty older version of the application from svn, surprisingly getting the same error message.

Comment: does your query return any values?

Comment: nope but I have data in the db for the id

Comment: I think that is why. EF gives you an error if nothing gets returned.

Comment: Try to modify your query to return any value, and see if you still get an error

Comment: I tried but no luck, I getting this error all over the place(wherever access the table). Even verified my  edmx file, looks fine. The edmx works fine for others though.

Comment: so it returns a value, but still getting an error? And you have all diagrams, model, and model.store?

Comment: yes right, everything was working fine until yesterday and not sure whats causing the issue

Comment: Use `Any` first before executing your Query. You need to determine if there is something to return before Querying for results.

Comment: @Aizen that is not the issue here, getting this error every time try to access any tables through entity framework.

Comment: Lol, I have the same problem... but I have empty table... Fresh database (with all migrations)... I have try is table is empty using `.Any()'